# Excel Dashboard Templates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, templates, dashboard

Are there any nice sites for *neat and free* Excel dashboard templates? The following one is a great example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this site : [free excel dashboards](http://www.freeexceldashboards.com/).

Some samples are to be found in <s>Microsofts's [The power of dashboard reporting with Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA012261271033.aspx)</s> as well as in [Dashboard Templates for Excel](http://www.officetemplates.org/dashboard-templates-for-excel.html).

You should also look into the site [The Dashboard Spy](http://dashboardspy.com/). Their About section also contains some very good stuff.